# How can I identify default parameters with integer value in php

Tags: php, function, default

I have a function with multi parameters and I want to call it in several places in my code. How can I call it with some default values like:

```
Addhistory($h_id, $h_name, $user_id=0, status=true)
```

So `user_id` and `statue` will have default values  when we will not pass it?

Thanks.

Comment: `($h_id,$h_name,$user_id=0,status=true)` this will do same what you want. isn't it?

Comment: Answer is already there in your question :)

Comment: H.H.e please check my answer i elaborated for you. if useful then mark and up-vote the answer.

Comment: peoples are not interested in telling problem solved or not? wastage of effort. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way, by assigning `$user_id=0` and `$status=true` you are defining their defaults.

Answer (score 0):

1.Defining the function

```
function Addhistory($h_id, $h_name, $user_id=0, $status=true){
    //do something with parameters
}
```

2.Calling the function with default argument values.

```
Addhistory(1,'example_string')//you need to just pass $h_id and $h_name as arguments if you want to call the function with default argument values.
```

[default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)